# How to 'interpolate' string variable beginning with ':' after '&' in scss.erb file

Tags: ruby, sass, erb

Within a scss.erb file I'm trying to add a variable to a mixin that allows modification of the context of a sub-style. While the syntax I'm using works within scss directly, it seems ruby is interfering because `&:` has a specific meaning. For example, in the scss.erb file:

```
@mixin test($pseudo: ":before") {
    color: #F00;

    &#{$pseudo} { content: 'x'; }
}
```

Later, in normal scss:

```
.my-element {
    // after pseudo element
    @include test($pseudo: ":after");
}

.my-element {
    // self
    @include test($pseudo: "");
}
```

Results in error `Invalid CSS after "  &{$pseudo": expected ":", was "} { conte...`

Actual context here: https://github.com/bjnsn/compass-fontcustom/blob/master/lib/compass/fontcustom/templates/stylesheet.scss.erb)

Thoughts? I'm assuming there is an escape sequence I could use for this, but Ruby is not my native tongue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in an ERB tag like this:

```
...
<%= "&" %>#{$pseudo} { content: 'x'; }
...
```

A little messy, but that way it's considered a string.